# I keep getting this error when I run netbeans 11.1 for the first time. Does anyone know the solution to it?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-11

The error that keeps popping up. I don't know what it's talking about. Can anyone help with a solution for this?
[image: Netbeans error]

Comment: Which version of Java have you got installed?

Comment: try "Disable Modules and Continue". This will disable the native Java-support in Netbeans. Then go to the plugin page and look for updates of `nb-javac`. If there are no updates available - try downloading and installing nb-javac directly from the apache netbeans download page. You can reactivate the Java-Support once the correct version was installed.

Comment: @mwarren java 11.0.4

Comment: @gamedroids when i hit disable modules and continue, it just closes it and nothing happens. i thought it would continue, but after waiting for 10 minutes I dont think anything is happening.

Comment: @gamedroids nevermind, just tried it again. It works now, thank you for your help!

Comment: glad to hear it!